# can't push image to ECR even though login in docker and was successfully

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

When attempting to push image to ECR, I always get 'no basic auth' error. ECR is in us-east-1.

This is login command

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email
```

I get response like this

```
docker login -u AWS -p eyJwYXl ...
```

I copy this response and run command, than I got this response

```
Login Succeeded
```

I assume that I logged in AWS and docker successfully, so I try to push image to ECR

```
docker push AWSID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repositoryname
```

Than response is like this

```
ed9f73170eb1: Preparing
f26c0d1885c7: Preparing
254cc70ba305: Preparing
6bfcbc08ecad: Preparing
0cb1addb8efc: Preparing
f9109426e338: Waiting
b7f99d06d826: Waiting
24d803cb9c1a: Waiting
25c4f6422338: Preparing
69b416623121: Waiting
0753f0746a0d: Waiting
a20143cd0986: Waiting
3028f693c3e6: Waiting
514a0f74b55d: Waiting
no basic auth credentials
```

To figure out what causes error, I checked `~/.docker/config.json`. my config.json is like this.

```
{
"auths": {
    "AWSPATH.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {
        "auth": "QVd..},
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
       },
"HttpHeaders": {
    "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.5 (darwin)"
}
```

Comment: you should see the user name and password in your config.json if Login is really Succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, jenkins server already had aws configured with different team's account. so I added region settings (we uses different region) and the problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an Authentication issue. Reconfigure your AWS-CLI, maybe that will resolve your issue.

```
aws configure
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: if OP is able to run `aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email` and get login token how it can be aws-cli issue?

Comment: I checked AWS configure files, they were fine

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was simply missing permissions.

There are a number of permissions related to uploading such as

```
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
                "ecr:PutImage"
```

I have solved it by adding them to my agent's allowed permissions.

Comment: I was missing `ecr:InitiateLayerUpload` and `ecr:CompleteLayerUpload`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to login this way and push:

`eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email | sed ‘s|https://||’)`